# Javascript. Convert image (<img>) to blob in Safari and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, blob

I need to convert image (pasted from clipboard by user in special `<div>`) to Blob in order to upload it to server. I managed to do it for Chrome and Firefox, but can't make it work for either Safari or IE. Although some of solutions I tried must have worked fine in Safari 9 and IE 10 (according to authors of the libs) but still failed miserably.

First off, I check whether the browser supports `clipboardData` (and that would be Chrome only for the moment) and then in `else` block I try to make other browsers do the trick. So, here is some approaches I attempted:

**1. My first semisuccessful shot:**

```
var pastedImage = new Image();

pastedImage.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

  canvas.toBlob(function(blob){$scope.uploader.addToQueue(blob);});
}
pastedImage.src = child.src; //child is the img pasted by user
```

Worked fine in FF, but wouldn't work at all in IE (this mockery of a browser can't even use its own console without additional patch which didn't deign to install itself on both of mine test PCs) and threw and exception in Safari as follows:

> TypeError: canvas.toBlob is not a function. (In
>   'canvas.toBlob(function(blob){$scope.uploader.addToQueue(blob);})',
>   'canvas.toBlob' is undefined)

**2. I used [JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob)**. The author claims that it would make `canvas.toBlob` work in Safari 6.0+ and IE 10.0+. Well, it just changed the error in Safari:

> SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through
>   the security policy of the user
>   agent.toDataURLcanvas-to-blob.min.js:1:923
>   toBlobcanvas-to-blob.min.js:1:923 onloaddirectives.js:411

**3. I used this piece of code to declare and implement `toBlob` manually:**

```
if( !HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob ) {
  Object.defineProperty( HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toBlob', { 
    value: function( callback, type, quality ) {
      var bin = atob( this.toDataURL( type, quality ).split(',')[1] ),
      len = bin.length,
      len32 = len >> 2,
      a8 = new Uint8Array( len ),
      a32 = new Uint32Array( a8.buffer, 0, len32 );

      for( var i=0, j=0; i < len32; i++ ) {
        a32[i] = bin.charCodeAt(j++)  |
        bin.charCodeAt(j++) << 8  |
        bin.charCodeAt(j++) << 16 |
        bin.charCodeAt(j++) << 24;
      };

      var tailLength = len & 3;

      while( tailLength-- ) {
        a8[ j ] = bin.charCodeAt(j++);
      }

      callback( new Blob( [a8], {'type': type || 'image/png'} ) );
    }
  });
}
```

It didn't change anything. The error is still the same.

**4. I used [jquery.image.blob](https://github.com/CoeJoder/jquery.image.blob) and changed my code into the following:**

```
var blob = $('#imgPasteArea>img').imageBlob().blob();
$scope.uploader.addToQueue(blob);
```

Again, FF accepts this solution but Safari throws this exception which points at the lib:

> Error: null is not an object (evaluating 'o')

So now I'm out of ideas whatsoever. Can anybody suggest a possible solution?